# Conservation of charge on Higgs production by bremsstrahlung

Tags: particle-physics, higgs, elementary-particles

The Higgs production channel 
$$q+\bar{q} \rightarrow W^++ H^0,$$
depicted below, seems to be violating charge conservation, or am I missing something?  The quark and its antiquark have the same magnitude of charge but each has different sign, while the $W^+$ has positive charge and the Higgs boson is neutral. Is this process really allowed?

[image]

Comment: the $q$ and $\bar{q}$ may carry different flavors (and when it is the case they coupled to the $W$ rather than to the $Z$). For example, $u\bar{d}\rightarrow W^+\rightarrow W^{+} H^0$ is allowed.

Comment: I'm kinda new to the notations of particle physics and had always thought that when we had $q$ and $\bar{q}$ on a process it was meant that it was one quark and its particular antiquark. From your comment I'm getting that this was a misconception and this is not the case, am I right?

Also, it would be implied that the up and down have enormous kinetic energies, since the mass on the RHS of that process is way larger than on the left, is this correct?

Comment: well, the notation changes from place to place. Somepeople would use $q\bar{q}^\prime$ or so. But since it is so trivial the requirement of charge conservation, often doesn't even appear explicitly in the notation. And yes, they are very energetic, at least as much as $m_H+m_W$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is based on TwoBs's comments.

The process is indeed allowed and charge conservation is not violated. The two quarks involved are not a quark and its corresponding antiquark. For instance, $q$ and $\bar{q}$ could stand for $u$ and $\bar{d}$, so charge would be conserved.

Comment: this is the relevant table http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Particles/qrkdec.html